# How to levitate non-static objects with oimo.js

Tags: three.js, physics

I use the oimo.js library (physic engine) with three.js and I would like my objects (not static) to levitate.

https://github.com/lo-th/Oimo.js/

I try to position the objects at a y value defined in my loop function but they keep falling.

How can I have these objects levitate while keeping non-static objects?

Here below my codepen to explain that :

https://codepen.io/ogames/pen/oNEWKLE?editors=0011

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.module.js'
import {
    OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
//import * as oimo from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oimo/1.0.9/oimo.min.js'
import {
    TWEEN
} from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/examples//jsm/libs/tween.module.min'

import {
    CSM
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/examples/jsm/csm/CSM.js"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// utils
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
export const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// variables
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var scene, container, controls, camera, renderer, light, ambient_light, additionalDirectionalLight, csm, stats, physics, position, body, world, ground_body, camera_body;
var game_start = false
window.setTimeout(() => {
    game_start = true
}, 1000)
//material
var m = {};
//geometry
var g = {};
//objects
var o = {};
//
o.enemy = [];
//class
class Enemy_instance {
    constructor(config) {
        var g = {}
        var m = {}
        this.config = config;
        g.body = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        m.body = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
            color: this.config.color_body,
        });

        // a lot of body
        this.body = this.create_instance(g.body, m.body, this.config.count, true);

        this.config.scene.add(this.body)
        // create several group and add dummy into it
        this.mesh = [];

        this.body.dummy = []
        this.physic_body = []

        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            this.body.dummy[i] = new THREE.Object3D()

            this.mesh[i] = new THREE.Group()
            this.mesh[i].is_alive = true;
            this.mesh[i].is_collide = false;

            // rename
            let mesh = this.mesh[i]
            mesh.position.x = this.config.posx[i]
            mesh.position.y = this.config.posy
            mesh.position.z = this.config.posz[i]
            this.config.scene.add(mesh)

            this.physic_body[i] = this.config.world.add({
                type: 'box', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
                size: [1, 1, 1], // size of shape
                pos: [mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y, mesh.position.z], // start position in degree
                rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
                move: true, // dynamic or statique
                density: 10,
                friction: .5,
                restitution: 0.1,
                belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
                collidesWith: 0xffffffff // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
            });
            this.physic_body[i].position.copy(mesh.position)
            this.physic_body[i].quaternion.copy(mesh.position)
            console.log(this.physic_body[0])
        };
    }

    //without having "this[obj]mesh"
    create_instance(geo, mat, count, fl) {
        let obj = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geo, mat, count);
        obj.castShadow = fl
        obj.receiveShadow = fl
        obj.dummy = []
        return obj
    }

    // for all instances
    animate_instance(obj) {
        obj.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            obj.dummy[i].updateMatrix()
            obj.setMatrixAt(i, obj.dummy[i].matrix);
            this.add_element(obj.dummy, i)
        }
    }
    add_element(obj, num) {
        let master = this.mesh[num]
        let slave = obj[num]
        slave.position.set(master.position.x, master.position.y, master.position.z)
        slave.rotation.set(master.rotation.x, master.rotation.y, master.rotation.z)
    }

    die(num) {
        this.mesh[num].is_alive = false
        this.hide(this.body.dummy[num])
    }

    hide(obj) {
        new TWEEN.Tween(obj.scale)
            .to({
                x: 1.2,
                y: 1.2,
                z: 1.2,
            }, 100)
            .yoyo(true)
            .delay(2000)
            .repeat(1)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
            .start()
            .onComplete(() => {
                new TWEEN.Tween(obj.scale)
                    .to({
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        z: 0,
                    }, 80)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                    .start()
                    .onComplete(() => {});
            });
    }


    animate() {
        this.animate_instance(this.body)
        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            this.mesh[i].position.copy(this.physic_body[i].getPosition());
            this.mesh[i].quaternion.copy(this.physic_body[i].getQuaternion());

            // contacts
            if (this.physic_body[i].numContacts > 0) {
                this.mesh[i].is_collide = true
                this.mesh[i].is_alive && this.die(i)
            }

            // no contacts
            if (this.mesh[i].is_collide == false) {
                this.physic_body[i].position.y = 2
            }
        }
    }
};

var data = {
    fade: true,
    far: 200,
    mode: 'practical',
    lightX: -.31,
    lightY: -1,
}

init_app();

function init_app() {
    start_physic()
    init();
    animate();
}

// init physic with oimo
function start_physic() {
    world = new OIMO.World({
        timestep: 1 / 30,
        // timestep: 1 / 60,
        iterations: 1,
        // iterations: 8,
        broadphase: 2, // 1 brute force, 2 sweep and prune, 3 volume tree
        worldscale: 1, // scale full world 
        random: true, // randomize sample
        info: true, // calculate statistic or not
        gravity: [0, -10, 0]
    });

    ground_body = world.add({
        type: 'box', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
        size: [100000, .1, 100000], // size of shape
        pos: [0, -.7, 0], // start position in degree
        rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
        move: false, // dynamic or statique
        density: 1,
        friction: 0.2,
        restitution: 0.2,
        belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
        collidesWith: 0xffffffff // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
    });
}

function init() {
    Minimal()
    create_object()
    init_camera()
}

function create_object() {
    create_ground();
    create_enemy();
}

function init_camera() {
    camera_body = world.add({
        type: 'sphere', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
        size: [10, 10, 10], // size of shape
        pos: [camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z], // start position in degree
        rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
        move: true, // dynamic or statique
        density: .0001,
        friction: 0,
        restitution: .5,
        belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
        collidesWith: 0xffffff1 // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
    });

    camera_body.position.copy(camera.position)
    camera_body.quaternion.copy(camera.position)
}

function create_ground() {
    g.ground = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100000, .1, 100000);
    m.ground = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xfce098,
    });
    csm.setupMaterial(m.ground)
    o.ground = new THREE.Mesh(g.ground, m.ground);
    o.ground.position.y = -.7
    o.ground.castShadow = true;
    o.ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(o.ground);
}

function create_enemy() {
    let c = {
        scene: scene,
        world: world,
        speed: random(8, 16) * .01,
        color_body: 0xbb1a1a,
        count: 50,
    }
    c.posx = []
    c.posz = []
    for (let i = 0; i < c.count; i++) {
        c.posx[i] = random(-20, -29)        
      c.posy = 20
        c.posz[i] = i * 7
    };
    o.enemy = new Enemy_instance(c)
}

function Minimal() {
    container = document.getElementById('world');
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2, 20000);
    camera.position.y = 0
    camera.position.z = -4
    // camera.position.x = -4
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
    camera.updateMatrixWorld()

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
    });

    //Shadows
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    //  ORBIT
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target.y = 0
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI
    controls.maxDistance = 10000;
    controls.minDistance = .01;

    //  LIGHTS
    ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
    scene.add(ambient_light);

    //PLUG IN SHADOW FOR HUGE SCENE
    csm = new CSM({
        maxFar: data.far,
        cascades: 4,
        mode: data.mode,
        parent: scene,
        shadowMapSize: 4048,
        lightDirection: new THREE.Vector3(data.lightX, data.lightY, data.lightZ).normalize(),
        camera: camera
    });
    csm.fade = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    world.step();
    o.enemy.animate()
    // copy position and rotation to three mesh
    o.ground.position.copy(ground_body.getPosition());
    o.ground.quaternion.copy(ground_body.getQuaternion());
    // physical camera
    camera_body.position.copy(camera.position)
    camera_body.quaternion.copy(camera.position)

    TWEEN.update();
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    csm.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Thank you for your precious help (I'm stuck on this question for 10 days without finding a real solution).

Comment: Look at the source code [of this demo](http://lo-th.github.io/Oimo.js/examples/test_terrain.html), and see how they update the position of the object attached to the mouse [in these lines](https://github.com/lo-th/Oimo.js/blob/5bf4d158b3325bec0d46fd64d116403ca663353d/examples/test_terrain.html#L337-L338). Maybe you could copy this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marquizzo,

It works with create an "new THREE.Object3D();" and set position with another object :

https://codepen.io/ogames/pen/mdXwbvr

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.module.js'
import {
    OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
//import * as oimo from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oimo/1.0.9/oimo.min.js'
import {
    TWEEN
} from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/examples//jsm/libs/tween.module.min'

import {
    CSM
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/examples/jsm/csm/CSM.js"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// utils
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
export const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// variables
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var scene, container, controls, camera, renderer, light, ambient_light, additionalDirectionalLight, csm, stats, physics, position, body, world, ground_body, camera_body;
var game_start = false
window.setTimeout(() => {
    game_start = true
}, 2000)
//material
var m = {};
//geometry
var g = {};
//objects
var o = {};
//
o.enemy = [];
//class
class Enemy_instance {
    constructor(config) {
        var g = {}
        var m = {}
        this.config = config;
        g.body = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        m.body = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
            color: this.config.color_body,
        });

        // a lot of body
        this.body = this.create_instance(g.body, m.body, this.config.count, true);

        this.config.scene.add(this.body)
        // create several group and add dummy into it
        this.mesh = [];

        this.body.dummy = []
        this.physic_body = []

        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            this.body.dummy[i] = new THREE.Object3D()

            this.mesh[i] = new THREE.Group()
            this.mesh[i].is_alive = true;
            this.mesh[i].is_collide = false;

            // rename
            let mesh = this.mesh[i]
            mesh.position.x = this.config.posx[i]
            mesh.position.y = this.config.posy
            mesh.position.z = this.config.posz[i]
            this.config.scene.add(mesh)

            this.physic_body[i] = this.config.world.add({
                type: 'box', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
                size: [1, 1, 1], // size of shape
                pos: [mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y, mesh.position.z], // start position in degree
                rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
                move: true, // dynamic or statique
                density: 10,
                friction: .5,
                restitution: 0.1,
                belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
                collidesWith: 0xffffffff // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
            });
            this.physic_body[i].position.copy(mesh.position)
            this.physic_body[i].quaternion.copy(mesh.position)
            console.log(this.physic_body[0])
        };
    }

    //without having "this[obj]mesh"
    create_instance(geo, mat, count, fl) {
        let obj = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geo, mat, count);
        obj.castShadow = fl
        obj.receiveShadow = fl
        obj.dummy = []
        return obj
    }

    // for all instances
    animate_instance(obj) {
        obj.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            obj.dummy[i].updateMatrix()
            obj.setMatrixAt(i, obj.dummy[i].matrix);
            this.add_element(obj.dummy, i)
        }
    }
    add_element(obj, num) {
        let master = this.mesh[num]
        let slave = obj[num]
        slave.position.set(master.position.x, master.position.y, master.position.z)
        slave.rotation.set(master.rotation.x, master.rotation.y, master.rotation.z)
    }

    die(num) {
        this.mesh[num].is_alive = false
        //console.log(num, "collide and die")
        this.hide(this.body.dummy[num])
    }

    hide(obj) {
        new TWEEN.Tween(obj.scale)
            .to({
                x: 1.2,
                y: 1.2,
                z: 1.2,
            }, 100)
            .yoyo(true)
            .delay(2000)
            .repeat(1)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
            .start()
            .onComplete(() => {
                new TWEEN.Tween(obj.scale)
                    .to({
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        z: 0,
                    }, 80)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                    .start()
                    .onComplete(() => {});
            });
    }

    move(num) {
        if (this.config.posx[num] < 0) {
            this.physic_body[num].position.x += this.config.speed
        }
        if (this.config.posx[num] > 0) {
            this.physic_body[num].position.x -= this.config.speed
        }
        if (this.physic_body[num].position.x > 30) {
            this.physic_body[num].position.x = this.config.posx[num]
        }
        if (this.physic_body[num].position.x < -30) {
            this.physic_body[num].position.x = this.config.posx[num]
        }
    }

    animate() {
        this.animate_instance(this.body)
        for (let i = 0; i < this.config.count; i++) {
            this.mesh[i].position.copy(this.physic_body[i].getPosition());
            this.mesh[i].quaternion.copy(this.physic_body[i].getQuaternion());

            // contacts
            if (this.physic_body[i].numContacts > 0) {
                this.mesh[i].is_collide = true
                this.mesh[i].is_alive && this.die(i)
            }

            // no contacts
            if (this.mesh[i].is_collide == false) {
                this.physic_body[i].position.y = 2
                this.move(i)
            }
        }
    }
};

var data = {
    fade: true,
    far: 200,
    mode: 'practical',
    lightX: -.31,
    lightY: -1,
}

init_app();

function init_app() {
    start_physic()
    init();
    animate();
}

// init physic with oimo
function start_physic() {
    world = new OIMO.World({
        timestep: 1 / 30,
        // timestep: 1 / 60,
        iterations: 1,
        // iterations: 8,
        broadphase: 2, // 1 brute force, 2 sweep and prune, 3 volume tree
        worldscale: 1, // scale full world 
        random: true, // randomize sample
        info: true, // calculate statistic or not
        gravity: [0, -20, 0]
    });

    ground_body = world.add({
        type: 'box', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
        size: [100000, .1, 100000], // size of shape
        pos: [0, -.7, 0], // start position in degree
        rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
        move: false, // dynamic or statique
        density: 1,
        friction: 0.2,
        restitution: 0.2,
        belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
        collidesWith: 0xffffffff // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
    });
}

function init() {
    Minimal()
    create_object()
    init_camera()
}

function create_object() {
    create_ground();
    create_enemy();
    o.paddel = new THREE.Object3D();
    o.paddel.position.set(10, 10, 10)
    scene.add(o.paddel);
}

function init_camera() {
    camera_body = world.add({
        type: 'sphere', // type of shape : sphere, box, cylinder 
        size: [10, 10, 10], // size of shape
        pos: [camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z], // start position in degree
        rot: [0, 0, 0], // start rotation in degree
        move: true, // dynamic or statique
        density: .0001,
        friction: 0,
        restitution: .5,
        belongsTo: 1, // The bits of the collision groups to which the shape belongs.
        collidesWith: 0xffffff1 // The bits of the collision groups with which the shape collides.
    });

    camera_body.position.copy(camera.position)
    camera_body.quaternion.copy(camera.position)
}

function create_ground() {
    g.ground = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100000, .1, 100000);
    m.ground = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xfce098,
    });
    csm.setupMaterial(m.ground)
    o.ground = new THREE.Mesh(g.ground, m.ground);
    o.ground.position.y = -.7
    o.ground.castShadow = true;
    o.ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(o.ground);
}

function create_enemy() {
    let c = {
        scene: scene,
        world: world,
        speed: random(8, 16) * .01,
        color_body: 0xbb1a1a,
        count: 5000,
    }
    c.posx = []
    c.posy = 20
    c.posz = []
    for (let i = 0; i < c.count; i++) {
        // pour générer du choix
        let rnd = Math.round(Math.random())
        if (rnd == 0) {
            c.posx[i] = random(20, 29)
        } else {
            c.posx[i] = random(-20, -29)
        }
        c.posz[i] = i * 7
    };
    o.enemy = new Enemy_instance(c)
}

function Minimal() {
    container = document.getElementById('world');
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2, 20000);
    camera.position.y = 0
    camera.position.z = -4
    // camera.position.x = -4
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
    camera.updateMatrixWorld()

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
    });

    //Shadows
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    //  ORBIT
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target.y = 0
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI
    controls.maxDistance = 10000;
    controls.minDistance = .01;

    //  LIGHTS
    ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
    scene.add(ambient_light);

    //PLUG IN SHADOW FOR HUGE SCENE
    csm = new CSM({
        maxFar: data.far,
        cascades: 4,
        mode: data.mode,
        parent: scene,
        shadowMapSize: 4048,
        lightDirection: new THREE.Vector3(data.lightX, data.lightY, data.lightZ).normalize(),
        camera: camera
    });
    csm.fade = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    world.step();
    o.enemy.animate()
    o.enemy.physic_body[0].setPosition(o.paddel.position);

    // copy position and rotation to three mesh
    o.ground.position.copy(ground_body.getPosition());
    o.ground.quaternion.copy(ground_body.getQuaternion());
    // physical camera
    camera_body.position.copy(camera.position)
    camera_body.quaternion.copy(camera.position)

    TWEEN.update();
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    csm.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```